# How to get current page number from url in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml, pagination, page

I want to check the page number which appears in a URL in a phtml file.
For example, if the URL is:

> http://localhost/magento/index.php/shop.html?p=4

How can I get the value `4` in the `.phtml` file?

I am using code:

```
<?php $this->getRequest()->getParam('p')?>
```

But it does not work in the phtml file. I am using Magento 2.3.2.

Comment: Good to see that you have resolved your issue. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('p')` to get page number.

Either you are in `.phtml` or in `controller` this will work

If it is not working for you then you can try this:

```
protected $request;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ....//rest of parameters here
) {
   $this->request = $request;
   ...//rest of constructor here
}
public function getIddata()
{
// use 
$this->request->getParams(); // all params
    return $this->request->getParam('id');
}
```

**Edit:**

I have used this type of code `$this->getRequest()->getParam('p')` in `.phtml` before and it worked perfectly for me

Comment: just clarifying here: the code snippet above must be put into a class. e.g. ViewModel or Block

Comment: `$this->getRequest()` should `$block->getRequest()`. `$this` usage in `.phtml` files has been deprecated with Magento 2. As mentioned in another comment, ViewModel is an even better idea.